# Sony experia z3 with bootloader bad

Tags: adb, fastboot

I have problem with my experia z3 and i can't fix it! I looking for help now. I try to unlock my bootloader but fastboot give me message **FAILED (remote: Command not allowed)** someone who know how to fix this problem ? 
Cheers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems driver problem.

try these:

Connect to flashtool (beta2 or beta4) with device power-on debug off, to see if flashtool can recognize it, and how much it can recognize.

Connect to flashtool with device power-on debug on , to see if flashtool can recognize it.

Connect to flashtool with device in fastboot mode, to see if flashtool can recognize it.

Connect to flashtool with device in flashmode, to see if flashtool can recognize it.

Flashtool may fix some driver error. I just succeeded after hours of bungling like that.